# Passing custom parameters into datatables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using DataTables to load data into a table - the data is massive so I'm using server-side processing which is working great. However, I'm unsure of how to pass custom parameters into my ajax call.

How can I do this and for multiple parameters (i.e. different buttons for different parameters)?

Here is my code, thus far:

```
<script>
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.reload = {
text: 'Reload',
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
    dt.ajax.reload();
}
};


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#landing_pages').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            keys: true,
            deferRender: true,
            responsive: true,
            "searching": false,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 500], [10, 25, 50, 500]],
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reload'
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{'url': "/data-source/landing-pages/{{profile_id}}{{page_dim}}", "data": function ( d ) {
            d.myKey = "myValue";
            // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
            // etc
        }}

        } );
    } );
    </script>
```

This is based from this example:
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to destroy the datatable, then reinitialize it with the parameters you want. Something like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.reload = {
text: 'Reload',
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {

    // Get the profile_id and page_dim values to pass in to the initializer

    // Destroy the datatable
    $("#MyTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    // reinitialize the datatable with the new call with the variables
    InitializeTable(profile_id, page_dim);
}
};

function InitializeTable(profile_id, page_dim) {

    var initTable = {
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
            keys: true,
            deferRender: true,
            responsive: true,
            "searching": false,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 500], [10, 25, 50, 500]],
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reload'
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{'url': "/data-source/landing-pages/" + profile_id + "/" + page_dim, "data": function ( d ) {
            d.myKey = "myValue";
    };

    // Initialize the data table with the parameters above
    $("#MyTable").dataTable(initTable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do i do this for multiple ones then?

Comment: Multiple what? tables? For tables, create a function for each table to be initialized, each with it's own ajax call and parameters

Comment: No parameters, sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I want to be able to pass dynamic parameters

Comment: you can pass the parameters into the InitializeTable function and you can construct the ajax call using those parameters. In the example, I pass in profile_id and page_dim as parameters and they are used in the ajax url construction. you may need to change that slightly to your needs